# Weird <t> tag inside snapshot

Tags: reactjs, testing, snapshot

When I perform snapshot using `Jest` and `@testing-library/react` in react component that uses `google-map-react@2.2.1` instead of `<GoogleMap>` component it's generated weird `<t>` tag.
Have you encounter such issue?